# Android Studio - setContentView Wont Display New XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, setcontentview

Very New to Android Studio and I am following a simple Udemy tutorial. I have:

1. Successfully created a main.xml file
2. Successfully utilized the file in the code: setContentView(R.layout.main);

Per the tutorial, I created a second xml file, with just a simple button, named "test.xml". I followed the instructions to utilize it in the setContentView:

setContentView(R.layout.test);

However, every time I run the emulator after the change nothing happens - I get a white screen that quickly closes, the app does not open. In the Run section I get the message "Success Operation succeeded." The build section states "finished."

If I repeatedly replay the app I get a message in the emulator that states: "App name keeps stopping" but no real info beyond that.

I think I'm creating the new xml file correctly: In the res folder -> File New -> Android Resource File -> Give it a file name (e.g. test). The new xml file then falls into the layout folder in my res folder.

I've created a number of xml files and I always get the same result. I don't see anywhere showing me an error.

I'm at lost for what I'm doing wrong in such a simple exercise.

Below is my onCreate code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testa);
```

Again - if I change "testa" to "main" it works.

Attached is the xml code for main and test files.
[xml file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCqdp.jpg)
[xml file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFSdr.jpg)

Comment: can we see your `onCreate()` method

Comment: can you  post your files here

Comment: I've added the onCreate code and the xml files above.

Comment: have you added any `findViewById()` anywhere in `MainActivity`? It could be crashing when switching layouts because `testa` doesn't have some of the views `main` has

Comment: Thanks!!! It was the findViewById()!!! Much appreciated! user3170251

Answer (score 0):

For displaying test.xml u need to add this to your xml file

```
      tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

and your .java file must named with MainActivity.java .

inshort if you want to bind any xml file with java class then add above attribute to main layout.and java file name must be same as in the tool:context="._____"

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I tried that earlier and it did not work. The initial code for the 2 xml files are are identical - except for background color. The end to the <androidx.consrtraintlayout.... code is as such for each xml file:     

        android:background="#5FB7DA"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"> 

Unfortunately this has no effect. The emulator still does not run the app.